# Switching from MacBook Pro Intel to MacBook Pro M2-Max

Tags: macos, time-machine, migration-assistant

I have a MacBook Pro Apple silicon M2-Max on order to replace my MacBook Pro Intel.

I have a few questions:

1. When I try to restore my system from the Time Machine backup, will my applications continue to work OK, or will I have to re-install everything?
2. Is it possible, when setting up the new machine, to tell it not to restore apps from the Time Machine, and limit the restore **only** to data?

Comment: When moving to a new machine with a different platform, use Migration Assistant to migrate your data and settings.  Don’t restore from a backup

Comment: Depending on the apps, you may have to re-authenticate or perhaps even re-download depending on the particular security mechanisms in place. Do use Migration Assistant, though, as Allan recommends.

Answer (score 2):

In general, applications will continue to work okay. You do not have to re-install everything.

There are some applications that do "just work" after being transferred from one computer to another. This is typically programs that requires a license code (serial number) or a cloud login that needs to be redone. This problem would also occur if you were switching from an Intel MacBook Pro to another Intel MacBook Pro.

Note that even though the application continue to work just fine - it is sometimes possible that you could get even better performance by upgrading those apps to versions that include builds for Apple Silicon.